# Why isn't a hasMany relationship used for an ArrayController model bound to changes in the store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I define the model for an `ArrayController` in an `Ember.Route` like this...

```
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('customer').get('memberInvitation');
  },
```

...then when I create a record using `createRecord` and `save` later then model does not show the new objects in the view.

But, when I set the model by filtering records from the store like this:

```
model: function() {
  var customer = this.modelFor('customer');
  var memberInvitationIds = customer.get('memberInvitations').mapBy('id');
  var idsParam = memberInvitationIds.join(',');
  return this.store.filter('member-invitation', {ids: idsParam}, function(memberInvitation) {
    return !memberInvitation.get('isNew');
  });
},
```

...then it does update the view.

Is there a right way to do this using the `hasMany` relationship? If not, what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Using the relationship should work fine. Here's why it wasn't.

The relationship was polymorphic, and the parent class did not have the `hasMany` relationship, so when the `memberInvitation` was created the `hasMany` relationship on the `customer` didn't realize it.

So, if the binding to a relationship seems broken, check the inverse side to ensure that everything looks right (especially if you have a polymorphic relationship).